# Why does Visual Studio 2012 keep adding "Debug" and "Release" solution configurations even after I delete them?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, configuration, solution

I have multiple custom solution configurations such as: CodeAnalysis, DEV-Debug, DEV-Release, TEST-Debug, TEST-Release, PROD-Release.

I have deleted the default solution configurations of "Debug" and "Release" dozens of times yet they constantly re-appear. Has anyone experience this before and, if so, were you able to prevent this from occuring?

Comment: This is a VS bug, it just doesn't deal well with trying to delete the standard configurations.  The only good way to get rid of them is editing the .sln and project files with a text editor.

Comment: Do you have any links to this being a formerly documented bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by opening the .sln file in a text editor and deleting the offending solution configurations.